# How to make a semicircle in place of the face?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

How to make a semicircle in place of the face? This operation must be performed on an existing meshes while in edit mode.

Preferably without addons, but if you can't do it without them, suggest an addon that will help
[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can bevel the 2 opposite edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>. If it needs to be taller you can first extrude the face with <kbd>E</kbd>

[image]

Comment: I need a clear semi-circle, not an uneven semi-circle

Comment: ok but why do you need to begin with a cube? can't you cut off half o a cylinder and extrude down? please tell a bit more about your purpose

Comment: The cube is just an example of a hopeless situation. In practice, for example, I make a robot or some mechanism. I need to do a given operation. And to do it with mathematical precision, not so that I can do everything by eye with a bevel.

Comment: The option is that I create a semicircle separately, cutting off half of the cylinder, and then merge what I get into the main mesh, in which I want to replace one fez with a semicircle. Then I still have to substitute this semicircle by eye. 

This is just crazy, there must be a better, faster, more convenient way

Comment: Blender is not a CAD, so it has another logic. I would work the other way around, begin with a cylinder. If you already have a cuboid and don't want to restart from scratch, create a cylinder, scale it to the good size and join. But maybe I miss a smarter way to do it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use <kbd>B</kbd> bevel, on edges, as @moonboots has described, for an exact semicircle.

If 'Clamp Overlap' is set, and 'Shape' is 0.5, and you deliberately overdo it, the result is a semicircle. (You'll need an <kbd>M</kbd> > Merge > By Distance to remove the vertices which meet at the middle)

[image]

Here 'Snap' is set to 'Vertex' and 'Active'. If your extrusion is not on a convenient axis, you'll have to create a Custom Orientation from the top face, and with that orientation active, work in its Z. ( <kbd>E</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> for the extrusion, <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> to slide back to base)

Answer (score 2):

We can use Edge > Extrude ( Spin option ) command.
YouTube vide for illustration of this method - https://youtu.be/2GoIiLlatkQ

Comment: nice, please describe the steps in your answer  ;)